# What events are triggered when a user clicks on a notification in notification center in ios/xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, apple-push-notifications

I'm using ios/xamarin to build mobile app and I want to determine which events will be triggered when a user clicks on a notification in notification center in ios/xamarin when the application is running in the background or not active.

I checked that the `ReceivedRemoteNotification` event is triggered when I click on the notification in the notification center either if the app is active or not.

Answer (score 1):

### When application is active:

If your application is active then following method will be called by default to receive notification:

> DidReceiveRemoteNotification

If you want to call ***ReceivedRemoteNotification*** by default then you will have to add key **UIBackgroundModes** with value **remote-notification** in ***info.plist*** file

### When application is in background

iOS will display received notification by it self. Currently there is no way to call any method in this case. So, when user will tap on received notification at that time again **DidReceiveRemoteNotification** method will be called, where you will have your notification regarding details.

### When application is InActive:

iOS will dislay received notification by it self, once again there is no way to call any method in this case. Now, when user will tap on received notification at that time **FinishedLaunching** method will be called and using following code you can have your data for both local and remote notification:

```
if (options != null)
            {
                // check for a local notification
                if (options.ContainsKey(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey))
                {
                    UILocalNotification localNotification = options[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as UILocalNotification;
                    if (localNotification != null)
                    {
                        //--your code
                    }
                }

                // check for a remote notification
                if (options.ContainsKey(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey))
                {
                    NSDictionary remoteNotification = options[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as NSDictionary;
                    if (remoteNotification != null)
                    {
                        //--your code
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Well explained. Could you elaborate bit more on calling ReceivedRemoteNotification by default?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Xamarin [documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/ios/). Another event is `ReceivedLocalNotification` based on usage. For Remote notification the registration workflow is also described there.

Comment: Thanks ,i tried but the ReceivedLocalNotification is not triggered as Im receiving remote notifications ,Im checking the documentation but still the same so far .

Answer (score 0):

Old question however if you or someone else still search an answer..

There is no event called for this action, but you can determinate if your app was started by clicking on a local and/or remote notification using the "options" variable coming with the FinishedLaunching method.

If null, your app was started normally, if not null then it was probably started by clicking on a notification in the notification center.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    /* 
    // Your init code, for ex.
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App(string.Empty));
    */                                                      

    if (options != null)
        if (options.Keys != null)
            if (options.Keys.Count() != 0)
            {
                UILocalNotification localnotif = null;

                if (options.ContainsKey(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey))
                    localnotif = options.ObjectForKey(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey) as UILocalNotification;

                if (localnotif != null)
                {

                    UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView()
                    {
                        Title = "LocalNotification",
                        Message = string.Format("Content: {0}, {1}", localnotif.AlertTitle, localnotif.AlertBody)
                    };
                    alert.AddButton("OK");
                    alert.Show();                                        
                } 
            }

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```